# ASP.NET Application - Restrict Microsoft Authentication subscribers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication

I have an ASP.NET application hosted as Azure App Service. This application is configured with Microsoft Authentication. But the problem is anyone with hotmail/live account will be able to access the application.
I wanted to restrict the access to my Application Pages to SPECIFIC hotmail/live users only.

1. What changes I have to do on Azure Portal?
2. What changes I have to do in my application?

Thanks,
Paraclete

Answer (score 0):

Applications typically have two "gates" of security - authentication and authorisation.

The simplest way would be to set up a list in a store (e.g. SQL DB - or hard code for testing) of authorised users. Let the Microsoft Authentication handle **authentication** and then use your list for **authorisation**. Redirect to HTTP Status code 403 forbidden if a user is not in the list of approved users.

You could make this a bit more fancy by implementing groups/roles, which is more elegant and manageable. Look in to the [ASP.NET Role provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-aspnet-role-provider-with-a-service) for built in functionality to expedite development. That said, some people find this build in approach cumbersome and roll their own simple provider and add it in to the page life cycle or the master page to share the functionality across all pages.

Comment: That was exactly my question. ASP.NET app uses Microsoft Authentication and all hotmail / live users will be authenticated. if I want to list down 10-20 hotmail/live ids, so that only listed ids have authorization to access my app pages. Where do I list/configure these Ids in Azure or App?